How to draw a drawable image on canvas android kotlin jetpack compose
@Composable
fun PokemonScreen() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Topbar()
        Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
            drawCircle(color = Color.LightGray, radius = 100.dp.toPx())
            drawImage(ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = R.drawable.pokemonimg))
        }
    }
}

The error which I am facing: under "imageResource" is:
@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function
Screenshot
I followed the instructions shown in android developers website.
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/graphics/draw/overview#draw-image
Still I am getting the error.

You just have to move ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = R.drawable.pokemonimg) to some composable function context like this:
@Composable
fun PokemonScreen() {
    val image = ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = R.drawable.pokemonimg)
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Topbar()
        Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
            drawCircle(color = Color.LightGray, radius = 100.dp.toPx())
            drawImage(image = image)
        }
    }
}

When you look at Canvas function: Canvas(modifier: Modifier, onDraw: DrawScope.() -> Unit) onDraw is not annotated as @Composable so you can't call composable functions there.
